# Old Kalkoff cross bike, worth restoring or not?

Tags: mountain-bike, parts, rust, restoration

I just acquired a used 21 gear old Kalkoff cross bike (cant even find correct model name). The frame and most expensive parts seem intact, so I was just wondering if it would be cool and inexpensive to restore bike: repaint, change faulty/old parts.

Community, help me identify how much would it cost to restore its functionality and aesthetic look. Which parts would you recommend and so on...

[image]

Here are the bike pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0aLz.jpg

Big thanks in advance.

Comment: This bike looks as if it was working, otherwise, why would it be chained up in front of an office building or university? So most likely, some spares as others have suggested and you're good to go.

Comment: Also, no offence intended, the bike seems to be in use. Is this actually your bike or are you trying to assess if it would be worth it to buy and or "acquire otherwise"?

Comment: I just got it (almost for free). Well, when i took these pictures I pumped tires, tried to fix gears (they jump off and stuff). It was for like 10 minutes. I keep it outside - in Denmark if you leave your bike unlocked, it is considered free.

Comment: Like I said, no offence intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a cross bike. First, make sure the bike fits you. If it doesn't, its not really worth restoring (give it to someone who could use it). It looks to be spec'd with relatively cheap stuff, so I wouldn't sink a lot of money into it.

The first thing to check is if the frame has any major cracks or damage. If that is in good condition, check the headset to make sure its working smoothly, that the fork is functional (it probably doesn't work well, but if it bottoms out automatically its relatively useless), the pedals turn smoothly, tires hold air, wheels are true, brakes work (probably will need new pads), shifters work, chain is OK, derailleur not bent. A lot of this will likely require elbow grease and real grease/oil rather than new parts.

If the fork is in bad shape, you can likely pick up a rigid fork for not much money, but you need some tools to install it which probably means a trip to the bike shop or local co-op. If you take it to a bike shop and ask the guy to give it a safety check, he should be able to quickly determine what needs to be replaced for a few bucks. As for aesthetics, well, not much you can do there.

In all likelihood though, all you're going to need to do is oil the chain, adjust the brakes , adjust the derailleurs, throw on some new brake pads, adjust the cables (some may be broken and need replacement), pump up the tires, adjust the seat and handle bars and you're going to be riding off.

Answer (score 0):

A bike gets into that age that parts get harder to find and more expensive.

That bike looks aluminum. 
I would not put much money in it. 
If you can lube it up and put new rubber on it then great.

I have a steel Bianchi 7 speed with XT and I am still reluctant to put much money in it. 
Can get cassette and a lot of the running gear - problem is shifters are hard to find / expensive.

That might be 1" head tube that is hard to find shocks for.

Bikes have come a long way.  You can get decent used bike with current components $400. 
It is not working putting $200 into a bike with components out of date.